# Java Arraylist Help

Tags: java, arraylist

Alright so I'm trying to get this class work:

```
public boolean hasPoint(Point p){

    for (int i=0; i<this.points.size(); i++){
        // Right here
        if(points[i].equals(p)){
            return true; 
        }

    }
    return false;     
}
```

However on line 3 I seem to be calling points as an array, but it's actually an arraylist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please refrain from editing the post, I already fixed your code formatting. For reference, next time just highlight your code and click the code button (the one with zeroes and ones); or indent it with 4 spaces.

Comment: @NullUserException, I never introduced it, only thing I had edited was the code changes.

Comment: @Anthony I see. You were working on a previous revision of the post. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access elements of an `ArrayList`, use [`.get()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29):

```
public boolean hasPoint(Point p){

    for (int i=0; i<this.points.size(); i++){
        if (points.get(i).equals(p)){
            return true; 
        }
    }

    return false;     
}
```

But if `points` is an `ArrayList`, you could just use [`ArrayList.contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to the same effect:

```
public boolean hasPoint(Point p) {
    return points.contains(p);
}
```